# How to implement char input validation in C++

Tags: c++

I need to create a program that calculates the price of a table being built.

**The main() function should call the following functions:**

1. A function which accepts from standard in the number of chairs to go with the table.
2. A function which accepts from standard in the surface area (in m2) of the table.
3. A function which accepts from standard in the type of wood used to build the table and chairs; ’m’ for mahogony, ’o’ for oak or ’p’ for pine. Ideally any other entry should be rejected.
4. A function that takes the number of chairs (N), the surface area of the table (S) and the type of wood (x) to calculate the price. The price for a table is x(S + 1/2N) where x is $50, $100 and $150 respectively for pine, oak, and mahogony.
5. A function to display the details of the purchase.

**Results at the moment:**

At the moment my code will only calculate the price of the table with 'm'(mahogony) and not the other two materials. For example:

```
Number of chairs: 5
Surface area of table (m2): 5
Wood type: m
Total = 1125
```

**If I change the wood type to 'o' or 'p', the same price will result.**

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int N;
cout << "Number of chairs: ";
cin >> N;

int S;
cout << "Surface area (in meters squared) of the table: ";
cin >> S;

cout << "Type of wood ('m' = mahogony, 'o' = oak, 'p' = pine): ";
char x;
cin >> x;

while(x != 'm' && x != 'o' && x != 'p'){
    cout << "Error. Invalid input. Please try again" << endl;
    cout << "Type of wood ('m' = mahogony, 'o' = oak, 'p' = pine): ";
    cin >> x;
}

int total;
if(x = 'm'){
    total = 150*(S + (0.5*N));
} else if(x = 'o'){
    total = 100*(S + (0.5*N));
} else if(x = 'p'){
    total = 50*(S + (0.5*N));
}

cout << "--------------------\n";
cout << "Details of purchase:\n";
cout << "--------------------\n";
cout << "Number of chairs: " << N << endl;
cout << "Surface area of table (m2): " << S << endl;
cout << "Wood type: " << x << endl;
cout << "Total = " << total << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are missing double equals char. Make it like this in your conditions: if(x == 'm'). One = means assigment, two = means equals.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int N;
cout << "Number of chairs: ";
cin >> N;

int S;
cout << "Surface area (in meters squared) of the table: ";
cin >> S;

cout << "Type of wood ('m' = mahogony, 'o' = oak, 'p' = pine): ";
char x;
cin >> x;

while(x != 'm' && x != 'o' && x != 'p'){
    cout << "Error. Invalid input. Please try again" << endl;
    cout << "Type of wood ('m' = mahogony, 'o' = oak, 'p' = pine): ";
    cin >> x;
}

int total;
if(x == 'm'){
    total = 150*(S + (0.5*N));
} else if(x == 'o'){
    total = 100*(S + (0.5*N));
} else if(x == 'p'){
    total = 50*(S + (0.5*N));
}

cout << "--------------------\n";
cout << "Details of purchase:\n";
cout << "--------------------\n";
cout << "Number of chairs: " << N << endl;
cout << "Surface area of table (m2): " << S << endl;
cout << "Wood type: " << x << endl;
cout << "Total = " << total << endl;

return 0;
}
```

You must == to check a condition and = for assigning value

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    float N;
    cout << "Number of chairs: ";
    cin >> N;
    float S;
    cout << "Surface area (in meters squared) of the table: ";
    cin >> S;
    cout << "Type of wood ('m' = mahogony, 'o' = oak, 'p' = pine): ";
    char x;
    cin >> x;
    while(x != 'm' && x != 'o' && x != 'p'){
        cout << "Error. Invalid input. Please try again" << endl;
        cout << "Type of wood ('m' = mahogony, 'o' = oak, 'p' = pine): ";
        cin >> x;
    }
    float total=0.f;
    if(x == 'm'){
        total = 150.f*(S + (0.5f*N));
    } else if(x == 'o'){
        total = 100.f*(S + (0.5f*N));
    } else if(x == 'p'){
        total = 50.f*(S + (0.5f*N));
    }
    cout << "--------------------\n";
    cout << "Details of purchase:\n";
    cout << "--------------------\n";
    cout << "Number of chairs: " << N << endl;
    cout << "Surface area of table (m2): " << S << endl;
    cout << "Wood type: " << x << endl;
    cout << "Total = " << total << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would help enormously if you highlighted the differences to (a) the OP's code and (b) the other answer, and discussed your reasons for both. As it stands, it may or may not be correct but is surely almost worthless.